# Build nested function

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction

By running the following code:

```
q[y_] = y;

For[i = 1, i <= 4, i++, q[y_] = q[If[1 - i <= x <= 2 + i, i, y]]];

f[x_] = q[If[7 <= x <= 6, 10 x, x]];

f[x]
```

I get:

```
If[0 <= x <= 3, i, 
 If[-1 <= x <= 4, i, If[-2 <= x <= 5, i, If[-3 <= x <= 6, i, x]]]]
```

and unfortunately I just can not figure out how to get the value of "i" and not "i" ultimate expression!

---

For example:

```
f[x_] = If[0 <= x <= 1 - 1/5, x,  If[1 + 1/5 <= x <= 2, -x + 2, 1 - 1/5]];

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

So, in short, I'm interested in building a function `f` with the characteristics described above and can not find an effective way to do this (what I have shown is the one thing that is the closest). The actual setting is really complicated to explain, all will be placed in a much larger program.

Comment: Please clarify what you're attempting to accomplish, and why you choose this approach.

Comment: Have you seen `Nest[]`?

Comment: @J.M. Once I understood what the `For` construct was trying to accomplish, I definitely ran into the same conclusion. :) - That is, imperative redeclaration of `q` is not very easy to understand and not very Mathematica-like.

Comment: @Manu, why not describe your actual problem and then maybe show what you expect to get from, say, two or three nestings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`If` has attribute `HoldRest`, which you can clear, but I don't recommend that.

I think the right solution is to replace `a[HoldedArgument]` by `a[#] &[ToDoBeforeHold]`, i.e.

```
q[y_] = y;
For[i = 1, i <= 4, i++, q[y_] = q[If[1 - i <= x <= 2 + i, #, #2] &[i, y]]];
f[x_] = q[If[7 <= x <= 6, 10 x, x]];
f[x]
```

Answer (score 5):

You may use `Piecewise`.

**For your `For` loop function**

```
g[x_] = Piecewise[{#, 1 - # <= x <= 2 + #} & /@ Range[4]]

Plot[g[x], {x, -3, 6}]
```

[image]

**For your example function**

```
f[x_] = Piecewise[{
   {x       ,  0 <= x <= 1 - 1/5},
   {-x + 2  , 1 + 1/5 <= x <= 2},
   {1 - 1/5 , True}
   }]

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Manu See update.

Comment: @Manu, Edmund's methods ought to be easily extendible by changing the appropriate numbers.

Comment: @Manu The key is `Piecewise`. Generate your list of *value-condition* pairs with your algorithm and enclose that list in `Piecewise`.

Comment: @Manu `Piecewise` evaluates its conditions in the order they are given and returns the value of the first condition that is true. Therefore you can `Join` your exclusion *value-condition* pairs to the list of *value-condition* pairs generated by your algorithm.  Then enclose this list in `Piecewise`. For example `Piecewise[Join[{{x, 0 < x < .5}, {-x + 1, .5 <= x < 1}}, {#, 1 - # <= x <= 2 + #} & /@Range[4]]]`.